# Are lower TDP CPUs slower?

Tags: cpu

If the clock speed, the cache size, etc. are the same, does a 65W Intel CPU run slower than a 84W CPU?  One example is i5-4690S vs i5-4570, http://ark.intel.com/compare/80812,75043

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, TDP is not a good indicator of processor speed, in-fact the i5-4690S is could be called slightly *faster* due to it's faster graphics bus and higher max turbo frequency.

What is happening is the i5-4570 came out in Q2'13 and the i5-4690S came out in Q2'14. So there there is a years worth of newer "techniques" that the engineers have come up with to go (slightly) faster while generating less heat.

Comment: It might be worth noting that lower TDP bins are typically more expensive (why give away something valuable to some users—lower energy use—for free?). Like speed binning, TDP binning is largely a result of manufacturing variation. Also, I *think* that if a thermal solution designed for a higher TDP is used, there *might* be greater opportunity for using higher turbo frequencies.